# Returning a time in String

Tags: java, datetime

I'm trying to write a method to return a Time in util.Date to a string. I am getting '0' when i am trying to return whether the time is in AM or PM and the minutes are not displaying the 0 in front. I am trying to return the time in the format of `HH:mm am_pm`

Here is my method:

```
public String getTime() {
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  int hr = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);
  int min = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

  return String.valueOf(hr) + ":" + String.valueOf(min) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
}
```

Input: 2:00 (HH:mm SimpleDateFormat in a JFormattedTextField)

Output: 2:0 0

EDIT: tried using the SimpleDateFormat but i am getting a type mistmatch error

```
public String getTime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
    date = format.toString().toString();
    return date;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: `cal.get()` always returns an integer.  `AM` = 0, `PM` = 1.  They are defined constants.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will do:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
String timeNow = df.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat` instead.

```
public String getTime() {
    // If you want the current hour
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm aa");
    return format.format(new Date());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM)` returns 0 for AM and 1 for PM. Replace the last line with:

`return String.valueOf(hr) + ":" + String.valueOf(min) + " " + cal.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == Calendar.AM ? "am" : "pm";`

Consider using `SimpleDateFormat`.